# Update MySQL query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to overwrite the current data in MySQL to be able to update everything.
I am new to this I don't see any errors with the below code:

PHP code:

```
<?php
// see if the form has been completed
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];

    if($firstname && $surname){
        // connect to the server
        include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");

        // check if that user exist 
        $exists = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname='$firstname'") or die ("the query could not be connected");
        if (mysql_num_rows ($exists) != 0) {
            // update the description in the database
            mysql_query("UPDATE firstname SET surname='$surname' WHERE firstname='$firstname'") or die ("update could not be applied");
            echo "successful";
        } else echo "the name does not edist";  
    } else echo "you need to enter both of the fields try again:";
}
?>
```

The error I get is

> The query could not be connected

but I tried the query and it is fine.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>update MySql form</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pageMiddle">  

    <form action="user1.php" method="POST">
        <div>
        <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" ></p>
        <p>Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update Description"></p>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should REALLY read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Is UPDATE query wrong I hate how people just look down on people i said I am new to  this

Comment: Instead of `die ("the query could not be connected")` try `die (mysql_error())`

Comment: I am gettin "No database selected" now  @ShankarDamodaran

Comment: Then you have a problem here `include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");` See if the file is getting included .. post the contents of it in the question.

Comment: I just done a internet connect 'mysql_connect ("localhost","root","pass123","worldoi5_social");
 mysql_select_db ("test") or die ("couldnt connect to the database");
 ' m @ShankarDamodaran

Comment: What is that `worldoi5_social` ??

Comment: That is my database name in phpmyadmin @ShankarDamodaran

Comment: Just do `mysql_connect ("localhost","root","pass123");mysql_select_db('worldoi5_social');` and test your code again.

Comment: I am not getting any where, I think i need to start all over with a different approach @ShankarDamodaran

Comment: Then you should start making use of [`PreparedStatements`](http://in1.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) as `mysql_*` is deprecated of PHP 5.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is called 'users' but you are running UPDATE on firstname. Change it to:

```
UPDATE users SET surname...
```

Then do

```
$exists = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname='" . $firstname . "'")
```

in order to isolate whether you have value for that variable. I would recommend printing the query string for testing purposes.

Comment: I am still getting the same result can someone please show a better way I don't mind starting all over